# What section of California plumbing code pertains to water main lines?

Tags: plumbing

Can someone please point me to California (US) plumbing code references regarding how water main lines should be buried between the house and street source? A plumber left an exposed pipe near the water meter and I'd like to have this information handy if they indicate that it's to code...

Answer (score 1):

Title 24- California Building Standards Code, Part 5 is the California Plumbing Code. It is based on the ANSI Uniform Plumbing Code. You can view it for free on line.

I do not think there is any requirement that it be buried. If you **do** bury it, it must be "... not less than 12" below average local frost depth..." and "...not less than 12" below finish grade...". See Chapter 609.

You should always ask your local Authority Having Jurisdiction.

Comment: Thanks. Any thoughts on what should be done if the meter is next to a steep hill? I'll try to post a picture.